# How do I repair damaged enamel inside my toilet bowl?

Tags: repair, paint, toilet

There is an area of enamel missing on the bowl of my toilet - just beneath the natural water line.

Is it possible to repair it with radiator enamel, or by some other method?

Answer (score 3):

No. The only solution that really works is a new toilet. You can try anything you want to try, but expect it to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Repairing the enamel at the bottom of a toilet is very possible with formulated enamel paints. These are usually rolled on- so the key to making it work is to remove all water from the bowl, dry and prepare in accordance with manufacturer instructions. Its not hard to do if you are careful, anyone who tells you otherwise probably works in the bathroom ceramics industry.